# logger.setLevel has no effect

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

code:

```py
import logging

logging.root.setLevel(logging.NOTSET)
logger = logging.getLogger('name')
logger.setLevel(logging.NOTSET)

def func():
  logger.info('1')
  print(logging.getLevelName(logger.getEffectiveLevel()))
  print(logger.handlers)
  **some code**
  logger.info('2')
  print(logging.getLevelName(logger.getEffectiveLevel()))
  print(logger.handlers)
  logger.setLevel(logging.NOTSET)
  logger.info('3')
  print(logging.getLevelName(logger.getEffectiveLevel()))
  print(logger.handlers)
```

output:

```
1
NOTSET
[]
WARNING
[]
WARNING
[]
```

I assume `some code` change the level of the logger (which I'm sure not the logger with name `'name'`).

But setting the level after `some code` does not work.

How should I set it back?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are only setting the level on the logger itself. If a loggers level is `NOTSET` the effective level includes all the parent loggers, since logs propagate up the logger hierarchy. If the root logger has level `WARNING` and the `'name'` logger has level `NOTSET` the effective level of the `'name'` logger is `WARNING`. (`'root'` is an ancestor of every logger)

The root logger can be accessed with any of these: `logging.root` or `logging.getLogger()` or `logging.getLogger('root')`. The level can be set the same way it is set on any logger:

```
root = logging.getLogger()
root.setLevel(logging.NOTSET)
```

Comment: So, how do I set the level of root logger?
I've tried setting by `logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)` at top but seems not helping